# How do I confirm database auto re-connection method in nestjs?

Tags: database, postgresql, nestjs

Guys.

I have one question about database connection in nestjs.

I used typeorm to connect postgres database as below.

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigServiceModule],
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    ...configService.postgresInitConfig(),
    type: "postgres",
    timezone: "+0",
    entities: ["domain/entities/*.ts", "./dist/app/domain/entities/*.js"],
    synchronize: false,
    namingStrategy: new TypeOrmNamingStrategy(),
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
TypeOrmModule.forFeature(entities.entityClass),
```

and then I realized nestjs is re-connecting automatically

although database server is rebooting.

(Isn't typeormModule only executed once when an application is launched?)

Where can I find the source code for automatic connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `retryAttempts` like so:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigServiceModule],
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    ...configService.postgresInitConfig(),
    type: "postgres",
    timezone: "+0",
    entities: ["domain/entities/*.ts", "./dist/app/domain/entities/*.js"],
    synchronize: false,
    namingStrategy: new TypeOrmNamingStrategy(),
    retryAttempts: 0
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```

Source: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#typeorm-integration

Comment: `retryAttempts` is only excueted when app is booted. right?